# Where is my mistake in defining a function?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I want to make instant search using php and java,but I keep getting this error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: searchq is not defined
 at HTMLInputElement.onkeydown`

So i want every time on key down to activate a function which will search for results in database and display results as a div.I checked all things to make sure all is good.Link .js file to my php page and to my element.Checked my code spelling mistakes,and i cannot find where my mistake is.Here is my code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
function searchq(){
 var searchTxt = $("input[name='food-search']").val();
 $.post("Food-Groups-BG.php", {food_data_bg: searchTxt}, function(output){
  $("#food-output").html(output);
  
 });
}
});
```

```html
<?php
mysqli_connect("localhost","myUsername","myPassword","dbName") or die ("could not connect");

if(isset($_POST['Food-Groups-BG.php'])){
$searchq = $_POST['Food-Groups-BG.php'];
$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","".$searchq);

$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM food_data");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count == 0){
$output = 'Няма намерени резултати!';
}else{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$fname = $row['title'];

$output .= '<div>'.$fname.'</div>';
}
}
}
echo($output);
?>

<!--**************************************************************
                             HTML 
***************************************************************-->


<p>Търсене на храни: <input type="text" name="food-search" id="food-search-id" onkeydown="searchq();"></p>
```

Any help is appreciated ! <3

Comment: Try removing `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {`

Comment: Oh you cannot remove it since you're using jQuery `$` inside. Before `jQuery(document).ready`, create a variable `var searchq;` and then inside `ready()`, assign the function to `searchq`.

Comment: You can remove it, as long as the code isn't run before the page is ready. Seeing as this code is in the onkeydown event of the input, then it doesn't have to be within the doc ready function. However, the correct solution would be as @ToJa92 posted - make use of jQuery's event handling for a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By declaring the function *searchq* inside another function (which is passed to ready()) you only make *searchq* available inside that function, and not globally. Instead of using the *onkeydown* attribute in your HTML markup I would bind the event using jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    function searchq(event) {
        var searchTxt = $("input[name='food-search']").val();
        $.post("Food-Groups-BG.php", {food_data_bg: searchTxt}, function(output){
            $("#food-output").html(output); 
        });
    }
    $("#food-search-id").on("keydown", searchq);
});
```

To learn more about event handling you can check out the jQuery documentation, for example [keydown](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/) and [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Woah that was fast,big BIG thanks to you man,now it is working,thanks <3.Would read the link which you gave me..

Answer (score 0):

Ali Yousuf is right. `searchq()` is only visible in the local scope of the `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {....})` handler function and cannot be accessed from anywhere outside. So you have to remove the jquery ready handler like Ali Yousuf said or define your function like this `window.searchq = function() {...}` to make it globally accessible